# Why do I get inconsistent equations when I resolve forces vertically and perpendicular to the plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

> Consider a body of mass $m$ kg on a smooth inclined plane inclined at an angle of $\theta$ to the horizontal. Let $R$ be the magnitude of the normal reaction force acting on the body.

If I resolve forces vertically, I get
$Rcos\theta=mg$

And if I resolve perpendicular to the plane, I get
$R=mgcos\theta$

Clearly this is not possible. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: What is $R$? A vector magnitude? What is $\theta$? A direction angle? With respect to what?

Comment: @BillN I’ve edited the question. Hope it’s clearer now.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, exactly, but it's closely related and might be a duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176200/why-taking-components-of-a-component-of-a-vector-is-invalid

Comment: @npojo That should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: Are you using Newton's 1st law on an accelerating object?

Comment: @Steeven I think I just did...that explains it really. But can you clarify what is then going on if an object is going around a smooth banked corner, with no tendency to slip up or down the plane? You can then equate up and down forces, as well as forces perpendicular to the plane, can you not?

Comment: Well, in the perpendicular direction there indeed is no acceleration. Also not on such a banked curve. In that direction Newton's 1st law is valid. But not in the other

Comment: @Steeven So we cannot resolve perpendicular to the plane using Newton’s First Law when a body is going around a banked curve?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/330695/why-is-r-cosa-mg-in-circular-motion-compared-and-not-r-mg-cosa Only seeing this now. The second answer to that question explains it quite well I think.

Comment: Be careful with the terms here. You can always resolve forces and components along any direction of your choice. But what you do next is important. You can only do Newton's 1st law on them, if there is no acceleration in that direction. If there is acceleration in that direction, then you must use Newton's 2nd law. In your question above there is *no* acceleration in the perpendicular direction. But there *is* in the vertical direction. So you can't use Newton's 1st law in both cases as you've done (as the answer below explains).

Comment: When you now mention a banked curve, do you then mean that you have a car driving around a circular curve which is banked (tilting inwards)? If that is the case then you have a different question. Then the acceleration is towards the centre of that circle (horizontally) and not down along the incline. That changes the whole picture. This information is critical and you should edit it in or ask this as a new question, if that is the case. A drawing / sketch would greatly help to show the whole picture

Answer (score 1):

If the body is moving down the slope, than there is vertical acceleration and you cannot equate vertical forced. If the body is static, there must be an additional force such as friction which adds to the vertical direction

Comment: What if the body is going around a banked corner (circular motion), banked at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal?

Comment: There is no way around this. If nothing opposes $mgsin\theta$ along the plane, the body will slip down.

Comment: But surely at the right speed, a body can negotiate a frictionless banked corner without slipping?

Comment: It's not a question of negotiations but a meticulous sketch of the forces involved.