# I think I broke Vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems

I was working on the following problem, when I ran into some trouble due to some repeated division of vectors into components.

[image]

I began by drawing the forces acting on the block. [image]

I pretended that the incline was the positive coordinate axes.Now, since the wall could only push horizontally, I broke up the downwards-left pointing vector into two components, one that goes directly outwards and one that goes directly downwards. However, the since the block doesn't move downwards, it must be applying another perpendicular force onto the wedge. So in order to find the net normal force on the wedge, I summed up this seemingly infinite series of vectors:

$N=Mg\cos(\theta)+Mg\sin(\theta)^{2}\cos(\theta)+...$

$N=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} Mg\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)^{2i}$

$N=\frac{Mg\cos(\theta)}{1-\sin(\theta)^{2}}$

$N=\frac{Mg}{\cos(\theta)}$

However, this normal force exceeds Mg! What did I do wrong? Also, how should I approach this problem? Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why taking components of a component of a vector is invalid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176200/)