# Component of component of vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors

Let's take an example to make you understand my doubt... A force $\vec{F}$ is in +$\hat{y}$ axis. First, I take $\pm 45°$ component of it both the sides against $\hat{y}$ axis... And then again, I repeat the same process, take components of these two, each one their  $\pm 45°$ components ... Resulting in 4 vectors... 2 along y and 2 opposite in directions along $\pm x$ axis... So by this way can we state that taking component of component of vectors is allowed?
Irrespective of this discussion:

[Why taking components of a component of a vector is invalid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176200/why-taking-components-of-a-component-of-a-vector-is-invalid)

And my second doubt was why is it so that we take components inside a quadrant only?... Like 30° or 60°...why not taking components of 130° or greater uncommon?

Comment: component of vectors is a scalar, you can't resolve any further

Comment: Technically, the $x$-component of a vector, for example, is also a vector, but usually after taking such a component, the magnitude is what we're really after, which is a scalar quantity. Taking the $x$-component of an $x$-component is allowed, but idempotent. As for your second question, vectors with angles defined to extend beyond quadrant $I$, is certainly not uncommon. Generally for a physical system we define a vector relative to an angle where the angle is usually minimized i.e; below $90^o$.

Comment: everything i've been reading recently says that a component isn't a vector. a vector is a thing that transforms like a vector. a component of a vector doesn't do that.

Comment: Are you projecting along vectors and then scalar multiplying the resulting scalar with the projection vector and then vector adding all the new vectors? In that case you are just summing vectors, which you can do all day long. But if "taking the component" is just projecting two vectors (giving a scalar) then you would need to take the component in a different vector space (the one dimensional scalar space with only onedimensional basis, 1, perhaps). This is my take on your question...

Comment: Oops, meant scalar product not projection. Lots of words with slightly different meaning...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a force vector as a sum of as many vectors as you want. Take the vector $2\hat{j}$, which I will write as $(0,2)$ for clarity. You can write this as two vectors:
$$(0,2) = (1,1) + (-1,1)$$
As three vectors:
$$(0,2) = (1,0.5) + (0,1) + (-1,0.5)$$
As four vectors:
$$(0,2) = (-1,-1/2) + (-1, 1) + (1,3) + (1, -3/2)$$
And so on, in whatever way you like. However, in order to find the resulting motion of a particle being acted upon by the force $(0,2)$, you have to use all of the vectors that sum to $(0,2)$. If you write $(0,2) = (1,1) + (-1,1)$, the particle is not alternately pulled to the left or right. The particle only moves vertically because the total force is only vertical. It is a mathematical convenience to decompose a vector into the sum of other vectors. A vertical force is still a vertical force, no matter how you write it down.

The only reason one vector in the sum would be ignored is if there is another force that cancels it out. For example, I'm dragging a sofa across the floor using a force of $(100, 50)\,\textrm{N}$. The sofa is heavier than 50 newtons, so the sofa stays on the floor. Because the sofa has no vertical motion, I can deduce that gravity and the normal force of the floor act upon the sofa to cancel out the vertical force. This results in a total force of $(100,0) = \vec{F}_{dragging} + \vec{F}_{gravity} + \vec{F}_{normal}$.